# Qt: errors after transformation from .ui to class file (.h)

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

This is the beginning of my ui_classname.h file generated out of the form .ui file.

```
#include <QVariant>
#include <QAction>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QButtonGroup>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
```

and after "build" I have 20+ errors like that:

```
QtProjects\build-slovar-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\ui_slovar.h:31: error: 'QLineEdit' does not name a type
 QLineEdit *lineEdit;
```

All errors about some Qt file or Qt macros. And all in that file.
It seems like MinGW compile it like cleae c++.
If I use Android build, it's ok, no errors.

Comment: You have not provided enough informations. Can't tell what's going on. Are you sure that headers are included properly?

Comment: Can you show the verbose output of the compilation line? Does it have the proper include path? Do you use Qt 4 or 5? With Qt 5, you will need QT += widgets in your project file.

Comment: I use Qt 5, Qt +=widgets did not help.

Comment: I started new project with ui form. I added only one QPushButton and tryed to compile...
C:\QtProjects\slo\build-slovar-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ui_slovar.h:27: error: 'QPushButton' does not name a type
     QPushButton *pushButton;
     ^

Comment: @Laszlo Papp - this could cause linker error, not name type error :) Stas, please include whole file ui_slovar.h, because i'm almost sure that error is placed somewhere else.

Comment: @Blood: sure, I just wanted to make sure that is alright, too, as it seems he forgot it, so it was worthwhile mentioning as an additional information, right? ;-)

Comment: Hmm ... I'm quite sure that when i wrote Qt apps, in Qt5 i had to include files like #include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit> etc. Try that

Comment: @Blood: err, no... that should not be used if possible because that will not work nicely with Qt 4. You seem to had lacked the proper include path when you tried it.

Comment: @Stas Shakirov: we would need a more verbose output of your compilation lines.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue in the meantime?